# When hovering over an icon to display an image, if image it is at the bottom of viewport, changes its origin

Tags: html, css

I have a table of records, and for each of the record there is an icon that when the user hovers over it displays the image for that record. When I hover over the icons for the last few records, the image expands the page further to display the image.

Current the top of each image is just below that table row. I would like when the user hovers over the icon and the image would appear below the view port, then move the image up to be in the viewport.

Both images were taken and the bottom of the view port.

Example can be found here: https://www.echomtg.com/set/KHM/kaldheim/

**Example Screenshot:**

[image]

**html:**

```html
<tr>
  <td class="text-end">1</td>
  <td class="">
    <span class="btn-icon btn-icon-primary">
      <img class="icon" src="/static/img/icons/image.png">
    </span>
    <span class="large">
      <img class="large-image" src="https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/front/c/7/c7bbb911-9de2-455d-9677-e1004db65dbd.jpg?1593559500" height="500">
    </span>
    Chandra, Torch of Defiance
  </td>
  <td class="">Legendary Planeswalker — Chandra</td>
  <td class="">Mythic</td>
  <td class="">
    <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/2.png">
    <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/R.png">
    <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/R.png">
  </td>
</tr>
```

**css**

```css
/* MTG Card Images */
#sets-individual-page .background .table .large {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#sets-individual-page .background .table .btn-icon:hover + .large  {
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
}

#sets-individual-page .background .table .large-image {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 18.75rem;
  height: 26.125rem;
  transform:translate(85%, 1%);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #sets-individual-page .background .table .large-image {
    transform:translate(10%, 1%);
  }
}
```

**Current Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: When you hover over the icon, the image that is displayed should always be in view port. if you go to the example URL Ive given and hover over the last rows name, the image appears above the row so it is in the view port.